# Does writing if statements differently affect the speed and efficiency of the program?

Tags: c#, performance

I an curious if writing `if` statements differently can affect the speed and efficiency of a program. So, for example writing one like this:

```
bool isActive = true;

bool isResponding = false;

if (isActive && isResponding)
{
     //do this
}
```

is it more optimal than:

```
if (isActive)
{
    if (isResponding)
    {
       // do this
    }
}
```

or is it vice versa or is there no difference at all? The reason i am asking about this `if` statement is because of the AND `&&` and the amount of `asm` functions it creates after compilation. Or how about:

```
if (isActive || isResponding)
{
   //do this
}
```

is this more optimal than:

```
if (isActive)
{
    //do this #1
}
else if (isResponding)
{
    //do this #1
}
//do this #2
```

Just like with the AND `&&`, i am curious because of the OR `||`

Comment: Compiler will deal with it (optimize), as a developer in c# you do not have to be concerned about it.

Comment: Head over to https://sharplab.io/ and very easily see for yourself.

Comment: There is no difference between the two snippets, the && operator uses ["short circuiting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  Which requires the compiler to emit an if-statement.  There *is* a difference when you write `if (isActive & isResponding)`, that eliminates a branch in the final code.  Branches can be quite expensive if the processor cannot predict them well.  This is not commonly done, it tends to trigger a WTF from a reader of the code.

Comment: Please note that since `&&` and `||` are short circuit, there might be a *notable* performance difference if you switch the sides of the conditions - `(fastCondition && slowCondition)` **is different from** `(slowCondition && fastCondition)`, sometimes a very meaningful difference.

Comment: This questions sounds very much like a [Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).  ...  *you should be more worried about the maintainability and readability of your code than its performance. And that is perhaps the most tragic thing about letting yourself get sucked into micro-optimization theater -- it distracts you from your real goal: writing better code*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not affect performance, because `&&` and `||` are so called "short-circuit operators", that is, statements they are linking will not be fired if there is no point in doing that.

For example

`if( true && myBoolFunc() )`  - `myBoolFunc` will fire because after checking `true` we still don't know if whole statement is true.

`if( false && myBoolFunc() )`  - `myBoolFunc` will NOT fire because after checking `false` we already know, that whole statement is false.

`if( true || myBoolFunc() )`  - `myBoolFunc` will NOT fire because after checking `true` we already know, that whole statement is true.

`if( false || myBoolFunc() )`  - `myBoolFunc` will fire because after checking `false` still don't know if whole statement is false.

And if you want some more details about how does it work, just read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

I've measured just for curiosity, and the results did not say there is a difference.

Test code:

```
private static void testIfs()
{
    int count = 100000;

    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int test = 0;
        bool isActive = true;
        bool isResponding = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive && isResponding)
                    test++;

        test = 0;
        isActive = false;
        isResponding = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive && isResponding)
                    test++;

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("using &&: " + w.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int test = 0;
        bool isActive = true;
        bool isResponding = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive)
                    if (isResponding)
                        test++;

        test = 0;
        isActive = false;
        isResponding = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive)
                    if (isResponding)
                        test++;

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("using 2 ifs: " + w.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int test = 0;
        bool isActive = true;
        bool isResponding = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive || isResponding)
                    test++;

        test = 0;
        isActive = false;
        isResponding = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive || isResponding)
                    test++;

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("using ||: " + w.ElapsedTicks);
    }
    {
        Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int test = 0;
        bool isActive = true;
        bool isResponding = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive)
                    test++;
                else if (isResponding)
                    test++;

        test = 0;
        isActive = false;
        isResponding = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (isActive)
                    test++;
                else if (isResponding)
                    test++;

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("using else if: " + w.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

Some tries (Release build with optimize code enabled):

```
using &&: 21449771
using 2 ifs: 20845600
using ||: 21025834
using else if: 21018318

using &&: 21041437
using 2 ifs: 21899080
using ||: 20442059
using else if: 21345493

using &&: 20629055
using 2 ifs: 20135598
using ||: 20407510
using else if: 20264467

using &&: 20152862
using 2 ifs: 19676131
using ||: 19910502
using else if: 19918131
```

Answer (score 0):

Has no effect for the scenarios what you are suggesting. The compiler automatically takes care of it and performs plenty of optimizations.


But even compilers have limitations. It won't know what values will be often assigned to the variables. As a developer, you would know that.

In your example:

```
bool isActive = <RETVAL_OF_SOME_FUNCTION>;

bool isResponding = <RETVAL_OF_SOME_FUNCTION>;

if (isActive && isResponding)
{
    //do this
}
```

Its quite obvious that we needn't bother with `isResponding` if `isActive` is false. Hence `isActive` should be present first in the sequence of statements in the AND condition. This will ensure that while running it'll not waste processing power to check for `isResponding` when `isActive` would be false.(just a sample example as `isResponding` would be false anyway if `isActive` is false)

While this is a very small optimization, it will not be done by the compiler. The compiler will have no idea what the variables represents. It'll just look for pre-programmed optimizations and implement it.

In this cascade of AND or OR the controlling condition should always come first.

There can be 2 possible scenarios for degradation of performance:

Too much data fetch

Too much fetch operation will drastically slow down your working. Typical fetch from RAM takes 200-300 processor cycles. Loading from L1 cache takes barely 1-3 cycles. Load too much data can/will also cause page faults, leading to loading from HDD storage, which is even slower. The processor will wait idly by during the load process

Poorly structured code

Don't use structures where some elements will be empty. An Excel cell is an example of that. Each cell has so many fields that copying one cell will copy a lot of info. I guess they may have implemented an optimized logic (dunno), but avoid using large data structures. It'll increase overheads during threading as well as when passing as function arguments.


Their effects may look negligible, but will add up in the long run if you are going to run it repeatedly in a system.

You don't need to bother with optimizations if the code will run less than 1000 times per day(depends on code execution time). The above optimizations I've talked about were actually implemented logic that speed up the code execution by about 60% in a system that runs continuously every 1us.

Comment: If by `<RETVAL ...>` you mean an actual function call takes place on the RHS, the compiler (in general) can't do this optimization. Even if `isActive` gets set to false, the subsequent function call to establish the value of `isResponding` may throw an exception.

Comment: @AndyAyers How do you say it'll be an exception? If the `isActive` is false, the `isResponding` would be false too ... atleast it's how I would have written the code.

Comment: To be concrete: if the code was really `isActive = x(); isResponding = y(); if (isActive && isResponding) ...`. Semantics require the the compiler to call both `x()` and `y()` in that order to preserve exceptional (or other side-effect) behavior, and then test the values returned. So for the purposes of this side discussion the value of `isActive` is irrelevant.

Comment: True. Both functions will be called. I gave this as an example only. It needn't be taken as an real life example. Actual good coding would be to first check for `isActive` and then inside the that `if` block, there can be another `if` checking for `isResponding`.

Answer (score -4):

actually the difference between the statement is the number of basic instructions  in this example:

```
if (isActive && isResponding){
 //do this}
```

here the cpu will calculate isActive  **and** isResponding than check the result if it's 0 or 1 
otherwise in the other code he'll do 2 checks the difference in terms of performance will spear if the **if** statemented is repeated in a huge among of times 
 i hope i could helped

Comment: "here the cpu will calculate isActive and isResponding" - no, it will only evaluate the second operand if necessary (in this case, if `isActive` is `false`): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator

Comment: Actually the compiler may in fact combine the checks -- all that matters is that the code behave "as if" the first check gates evaluation of the second check. But because the second check is side-effect free the compiler may decide to evaluate both and do just one test. Whether this is a profitable optimization or not depends on a number of factors.

Comment: Additionally, [if the JIT Compiler determines these be always be false, it will optimize the call out of the executing code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904673.aspx).. as it if never existed...